# Where in the Material 3 TopAppBar code is the padding defined?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3

I know that the `TopAppBar` in Material 3 has a [Left/right padding of 16dp](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/specs#5864f97e-59c4-4d32-83dc-a5c48c956d8f). However I am wondering where in the source code that is defined? For example, the TopAppBar constructor looks like this - no hint to the default left/right padding.

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun TopAppBar(
    title: @Composable () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navigationIcon: @Composable () -> Unit = {},
    actions: @Composable RowScope.() -> Unit = {},
    windowInsets: WindowInsets = TopAppBarDefaults.windowInsets,
    colors: TopAppBarColors = TopAppBarDefaults.topAppBarColors(),
    scrollBehavior: TopAppBarScrollBehavior? = null
) {
    SingleRowTopAppBar(
        modifier = modifier,
        title = title,
        titleTextStyle = MaterialTheme.typography.fromToken(TopAppBarSmallTokens.HeadlineFont),
        centeredTitle = false,
        navigationIcon = navigationIcon,
        actions = actions,
        windowInsets = windowInsets,
        colors = colors,
        scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior
    )
}
```

Is there is any constant I can use to apply this padding to other components or do I have to hardcode the 16dp? I want the things below the `TopAppBar` to have the same left/right padding, otherwise it does not look consistent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is defined further down the call chain inside the `TopAppBarLayout` composable, inside the `titlePlaceable.placeRelative` section.

Here are the relevant code sections

```kotlin
Box(
    Modifier
        .layoutId("navigationIcon")
        .padding(start = TopAppBarHorizontalPadding) // <-- line of interest
) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalContentColor provides navigationIconContentColor,
        content = navigationIcon
    )
}
Box(
    Modifier
        .layoutId("title")
        .padding(horizontal = TopAppBarHorizontalPadding) // <-- line of interest
        // ...
) {
    ProvideTextStyle(value = titleTextStyle) {
        CompositionLocalProvider(
            LocalContentColor provides titleContentColor.copy(alpha = titleAlpha),
            content = title
        )
    }
}
```

```kotlin
layout(constraints.maxWidth, layoutHeight) {
    // Navigation icon
    navigationIconPlaceable.placeRelative(
        x = 0,
        y = (layoutHeight - navigationIconPlaceable.height) / 2
    )
    // Title
    titlePlaceable.placeRelative(
        x = when (titleHorizontalArrangement) {
            Arrangement.Center -> (constraints.maxWidth - titlePlaceable.width) / 2
            Arrangement.End ->
                constraints.maxWidth - titlePlaceable.width - actionIconsPlaceable.width
            // Arrangement.Start.
            // An TopAppBarTitleInset will make sure the title is offset in case the
            // navigation icon is missing.
            else -> max(TopAppBarTitleInset.roundToPx(), navigationIconPlaceable.width)
        },
    // ...
```

And this are the values used in the code above

```kotlin
private val TopAppBarHorizontalPadding = 4.dp
private val TopAppBarTitleInset = 16.dp - TopAppBarHorizontalPadding
```

These are defined as part of the library so they are basically constants, and are unlikely to change between versions. Even if they ever change, you have control over when to update the library and at that point you would also update your paddings to match again.

So when the top app bar does not display a navigation icon, the padding at the `start` side is `12.dp` and then the title `Box` follows, which has its own padding of `4.dp` for a total of `16.dp` of padding.

And when the top bar does display a navigation icon the padding at the `start` side is `0.dp` then the navigation icon `Box` follows, which has its own padding of `4.dp` for a total of `4.dp` of padding.
However, usually the navigation icons are added by using an `IconButton` and adding an `Icon` as content to it. The minimum (touch) size of the `IconButton` is `48.dp` (defined inside the `IconButton` composable) and the default `Icon` size is `24.dp`. This means that even though the actual padding is 4.dp the "visual" padding up to the side of the `Icon` is `4.dp + (48.dp / 2 - 24.dp / 2) = 4.dp + 12.dp` = `16.dp`.

It is similar on the `end` side where the action icons are or where the title ends (when there are no action icons).

So in both cases (as long as you are using default icon sizes) the "visual" paddings are the same at `16.dp`. So if you decide to go with a padding of `16.dp` for your content the layouts will look aligned.

Note, that all this is assuming that the left/right `windowInsets` are 0, which might not be the case on all devices and all orientations.

So to ensure that the layouts look aligned in all cases you also need to take `windowInsets` into consideration in your layout. If you are already, then things should align correctly when you add `16.dp` of padding. If you are not, then you either need to apply `windowInsets` to you (parent) composable (this should be the easier option) or you need to add the `windowInsets` to the calculations for the correct side based on `LayoutDirection` by calling `calculateLeftPadding` and `calculateRightPadding`.

```
val ld = LocalLayoutDirection.current
val insets = windowInsets.asPaddingValues(LocalDensity.current)
val leftPadding = insets.calculateLeftPadding(ld)
val rightPadding = insets.calculateRightPadding(ld)
```

Comment: awesome, thank you for these detailed informations!